# Three js merging Geometries and Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three js ver67
Current code something like this -

```
    var materials = [];
    var totalGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
    var cubeMat;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSetArray.length; i++) {
        var ptColor = dataSetArray[i].color;
        var value = dataSetArray[i].value;
        var position = latLongToVector3(dataSetArray[i].y, dataSetArray[i].x, 600, 1);

        var cubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 1 + value / 20);


        cubeMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: new THREE.Color(ptColor),
            opacity: 0.6
        });


        materials.push(cubeMat);
        // cubeGeom.updateMatrix();

        var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, cubeMat);
        cubeMesh.position = position;
        cubeMesh.lookAt(scene.position);

        // totalGeom.merge(cubeMesh.geometry, cubeMesh.geometry.matrix);
        //THREE.GeometryUtils.setMaterialIndex(cubeMesh.geometry, i);
        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(totalGeom, cubeMesh);
    }


    var total = new THREE.Mesh(totalGeom, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    scene.add(total);
```

However I get the message

DEPRECATED: GeometryUtils's .merge() has been moved to Geometry. Use geometry.merge( geometry2, matrix, materialIndexOffset ) instead.

in chrome dev tools.

When I try something like  -
totalGeom.merge(cubeMesh.geometry, cubeMesh.geometry.matrix); 
instead of  THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(totalGeom, cubeMesh); I get exceptions.

How will I do the above merge? Please help.

Comment: Try `cubeMesh.updateMatrix(); totalGeom.merge(cubeMesh.geometry, cubeMesh.matrix);` But before you do that, use `cubeMesh.position.copy( position )` instead of `cubeMesh.position = position;`

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the cubeMesh.position.copy( position ) tip.

Comment: I always get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined`. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note: This answer applies to legacy versions of three.js.

---

Do this:

```
cubeMesh.updateMatrix();
totalGeom.merge( cubeMesh.geometry, cubeMesh.matrix );
```

For a further understanding, see the source code of `THREE.Geometry.merge()`.

three.js r.69