# Preserve UV map when using mesh merge in Three.js

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I am currently following [this tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/08/02/how-to-do-a-procedural-city-in-100lines/) by Jerome Etienne on generating a procedural city using Three.js. The tutorial uses revision 59 of Three.js while I am working with revision 73.

The problem comes from this line in the tutorial,

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( cityGeometry, buildingMesh );
```

The method is no longer available. The new way to accomplish this according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24433115/2354735) is,

```
buildingMesh.updateMatrix();
cityGeometry.merge( buildingMesh.geometry, buildingMesh.matrix );
```

However, when I do this, the location of the roof in the UV map changes.

This is what it looks like when I render the buildings individually.
[image: without merge]

And this is what it looks like when I merge them. Notice the roof location in the UV map.
[image]

Specification of the roof's UV map is per the tutorial. Specifically,

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][4][0].set( 0, 0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][4][1].set( 0, 0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][4][2].set( 0, 0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][5][0].set( 0, 0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][5][1].set( 0, 0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][5][2].set( 0, 0 );
```

and the `buildingMesh` is created as follows (in a for loop where n is the number of buildings),

```
var buildingMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );
```

What do I need to change or do differently in order for the merged mesh to respect the geometry's UV map?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses the latest `three.js` version (v79). From your code, I don't see how my update is different from yours, but all roofs are rendered correctly:

https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/WrbvEz?editors=0010