# Improving three.js performance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am visualizing biological data (neurons) in my website.
I have drawn the neuron which consists of a considerable number of spheres and cylinders. The problem is that the scene is really slow (The auto-rotating and controlling the scene with the mouse).
In desktop applications, I used to use DisplayList in OpenGL which improve the performance in a great way. Does THREE.js have an equivalent to the displaylist? or does it have what raise its performance?

This is my code:

```
<script>
    var container, stats;
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var neuron, neuron_center;

    var sphere_material_soma = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    wireframe: false,
    color: 0x0000ff,
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 30});

    var sphere_material_bif = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    wireframe: false,
    color: 0x00ff00,
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 30});

    var sphere_material_tip = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    wireframe: false,
    color: 0xffff00,
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 30});

    var sphere_material_normal = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff0000, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30});     


    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.getElementById('visualization');

        neuron_center = new THREE.Vector3({{ neuron.center.x }}, {{ neuron.center.y }}, {{ neuron.center.z }});

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);
        camera.position.z = neuron_center.z + 200;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        neuron = new THREE.Group();


        draw_neuron();

        scene.add(neuron);

        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        dirLight.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
        scene.add(dirLight);

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0xbbbbbb);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(960 / 720);
        renderer.setSize(960, 720);

        stats = new Stats();

        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        container.appendChild(stats.dom);    

    } 

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        stats.begin();
        render();
        stats.end();
    }

    function render() { 

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }      


    function draw_neuron() {

        {% for link in links %}

            var n_position = new THREE.Vector3({{ link.0.position.x }}-neuron_center.x,
                    {{ link.0.position.y }}-neuron_center.y, {{ link.0.position.z }}-neuron_center.z);
            var p_position = new THREE.Vector3({{ link.1.position.x }}-neuron_center.x,
                    {{ link.1.position.y }}-neuron_center.y, {{ link.1.position.z }}-neuron_center.z);                      

            var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry({{ link.0.radius }}, 10, 10);
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, sphere_material_soma);
            sphere.position.set(n_position.x, n_position.y, n_position.z);
            neuron.add(sphere);

           {%  if link.0.type.id == 5 %}
            sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, sphere_material_soma);
           {% elif link.0.type.id == 6 %}
            sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, sphere_material_bif);
           {% elif link.0.type.id == 7 %}
            sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, sphere_material_tip);
           {% else %}
            sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, sphere_material_normal);
           {% endif %}

            neuron.add(c);

        {% endfor %}

    }

    function draw_cylinder(start, end, radius_start, radius_end, material) {
        var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
        direction.subVectors(end, start);

        var mid_x = start.x + end.x;
        var mid_y = start.y + end.y;
        var mid_z = start.z + end.z;
        var mid_vector = new THREE.Vector3(mid_x, mid_y, mid_z);


        var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(radius_start, radius_end, direction.length(), 10, 10);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        mesh.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(axis, direction.clone().normalize());
        var temp = mesh.position;

        mesh.position.copy(mid_vector.clone().multiplyScalar(0.5));

        return mesh;
    }

</script>
```

I haven't included the complete code because it is big, so I have excluded the variables and the events handlers since they only deal with teh mouse and some drawing options.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: every mesh you have in scene equals one drawcall, drawcalls are slow, all your neurons have the same materials so you can merge your geometries into one big geometry and fps should increase take a look at this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422289/three-js-merging-geometries-and-mesh

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik Thanks for the answer, but actually, I have many materials and just didn't write them here so I will edit the code in the question. I didn't want to confuse you with many if/else statements. Sorry for this

Comment: Look into [instancing](http://threejs.org/examples/?q=insta#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic).

Comment: @The Maestro still you have only few materials, merge geometries that have the same material (for starters create a map `bigGeometries[material.uuid]`) and you will have few Meshes, WebGL can handle ~hundreds of them before getting sluggish -

Comment: In my experience, fixes for something as straightforward like this are likely to be found among the examples at [threejs.org/examples](http://threejs.org/examples). Maybe just choose your renderer, WebGL, for example, and scan the relevant example section for something similar?