# THREE.js high CPU usage

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, cpu-usage

I was messing with some terrain generation using THREE.js, and I'm getting horrible performance. The frame rate is very low, and whenever the camera is moving the process's CPU usage is around 95%.

I was able to prevent the high CPU usage when not moving by simply not re-rendering the scene unless the camera has moved, but the CPU usage is still near 100% when moving. This method also makes it seem more choppy and I don't think this will be a viable option as I add new features.

I've seen demos [like this](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html) where thousands of cubes are animated and the frame rate/CPU usage is fine, so I know there has to be a way to do this more efficiently.

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";

let WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
let HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
const BLOCK_SIZE = 20;
const Colors = {
    blue: 0x2194CE
};

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: Colors.blue
});

function Block() {
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
}

function generateTerrain(scene) {
    const size = 33;
    let map = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        const ary = Array.apply(null, Array(size)).map(function() { return 0; })
        map.push(ary);
    }
    map[size - 1][size - 1] = 6;
    map[0][size - 1] = 3;
    map[size - 1][0] = 3;

    let subSize = size - 1;

    for (let iter = 0; iter < 2; iter++) {
        // square:
        for (let i = 0; i < size - subSize; i += subSize) {
            for (let j = 0; j < size - subSize; j += subSize) {
                const points = [map[j][i], map[j][i + subSize], map[j + subSize][i], map[j + subSize][i + subSize]];
                const avg = points.reduce((s, v) => s + v) / points.length;
                map[j + subSize / 2][i + subSize / 2] = Math.round(avg + Math.random() * subSize / 2);
            }
        }

        // diamond:
        for (let j = 0; j <= size - 1; j += subSize / 2) {
            for (let i = (subSize / 2 + j) % subSize; i <= size - 1; i += subSize) {
                let points = [[i, j - subSize / 2], [i, j + subSize / 2], [i + subSize / 2, j], [i - subSize / 2, j]];
                points = points.filter(p => p[0] >= 0 && p[1] >= 0 && p[0] < size && p[1] < size);
                const avg = points.reduce((s, v) => map[v[1]][v[0]] + s, 0) / points.length;
                map[j][i] = Math.round(avg + Math.random() * subSize / 2);
            }
        }

        subSize /= 2;
    }

    // bilinear interpolation:

    for (let y = 0; y < size; y += 8) {
        for (let x = 0; x < size; x += 8) {
            for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                const p1 = map[y][x];
                let p2, p3;
                if (x != size - 1) {
                    p2 = map[y][x + 8];
                    const valx = (i / 8) * (p2 - p1) + p1;
                    map[y][x + i] = Math.round(valx);
                }

                if (y != size - 1) {
                    p3 = map[y + 8][x];
                    const valy = (i / 8) * (p3 - p1) + p1;
                    map[y + i][x] = Math.round(valy);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (let y = 0; y < size - 1; y += 8) {
        for (let x = 0; x < size - 1; x += 8) {
            for (let j = 1; j < 8; j++) {
                const p1 = map[y][x + j];
                const p2 = map[y + 8][x + j];
                for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                    const val = (i / 8) * (p2 - p1) + p1;
                    map[y + i][x + j] = Math.round(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // draw it:

    for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (var h = 0; h <= map[y][x]; h++) {
                const block = new Block();
                block.mesh.position.set(x * BLOCK_SIZE, h * BLOCK_SIZE, -y * BLOCK_SIZE);
                scene.add(block.mesh);
            }
            if (map[y][x] < 0) {
                const block = new Block();
                block.mesh.position.set(x * BLOCK_SIZE, map[y][x] * BLOCK_SIZE, -y * BLOCK_SIZE);
                scene.add(block.mesh);
            }
        }
    }

}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 3000);
camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";

camera.position.set(75, 550, 500);
camera.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 6;
camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 8;

const hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xAAAAAA, 0x000000, 0.9);
const shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.9);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xDC8874, 0.3);

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xF7D9AA, 550, 1500);

shadowLight.position.set(-10, 75, 25);
shadowLight.shadow.camera.left = -500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.right = 500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.top = 500;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -700;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
shadowLight.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
shadowLight.castShadow = true;


scene.add(hemisphereLight);
scene.add(shadowLight);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const keysDown = { up: false, down: false, left: false, right: false,
                   forward: false, backward: false };

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 65: // a
        case 37:
            keysDown.left = true;
            break;
        case 68: // d
        case 39:
            keysDown.right = true;
            break;
        case 87: // w
        case 38:
            keysDown.forward = true;
            break;
        case 83: // s
        case 40:
            keysDown.backward = true;
            break;
        case 32:
            keysDown.up = true;
            break;
        case 16:
            keysDown.down = true;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 65: // a
        case 37:
            keysDown.left = false;
            break;
        case 68: // d
        case 39:
            keysDown.right = false;
            break;
        case 87: // w
        case 38:
            keysDown.forward = false;
            break;
        case 83: // s
        case 40:
            keysDown.backward = false;
            break;
        case 32:
            keysDown.up = false;
            break;
        case 16:
            keysDown.down = false;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
});

let initialPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let currentRotation = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let isDragging = false;
let pastRotation = { x: camera.rotation.x, y: camera.rotation.y };

const fps = 1000 / 30;
let then = Date.now();
let now;

let needsUpdate = true;

function update() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }, fps);

    const amount = 10;
    const theta = -camera.rotation.y;
    if (keysDown.forward) {
        camera.position.x += amount * Math.sin(theta);
        camera.position.z -= amount * Math.cos(theta);
        needsUpdate = true;
    }
    if (keysDown.backward) {
        camera.position.x -= amount * Math.sin(theta);
        camera.position.z += amount * Math.cos(theta);
        needsUpdate = true;
    }
    if (keysDown.left) {
        camera.position.x -= amount * Math.cos(theta);
        camera.position.z -= amount * Math.sin(theta);
        needsUpdate = true;
    }
    if (keysDown.right) {
        camera.position.x += amount * Math.cos(theta);
        camera.position.z += amount * Math.sin(theta);
        needsUpdate = true;
    }
    if (keysDown.up) {
        camera.position.y += amount;
        needsUpdate = true;
    }
    if (keysDown.down) {
        camera.position.y -= amount;
        needsUpdate = true;
    }

    // this is my attempt at improving the preformance, but it only helps when the camera is not moving. Plus, it assumes nothing else in the scene will move which may not be true in the future
    if (needsUpdate) {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        needsUpdate = false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
    initialPos = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    isDragging = false;
    pastRotation.x += currentRotation.x;
    pastRotation.y += currentRotation.y;
    currentRotation = { x: 0, y: 0 };
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (!isDragging) { return; }

    needsUpdate = true;

    const factor = 0.001;

    currentRotation.x = factor * (e.clientY - initialPos.y);
    currentRotation.y = factor * (e.clientX - initialPos.x);

    camera.rotation.x = pastRotation.x + currentRotation.x;
    camera.rotation.y = pastRotation.y + currentRotation.y;
});

generateTerrain(scene);

update();
```

Comment: How many block.mesh are you adding to the scene? It seems you may be adding thousands of meshes all sharing the same material and geometry, in which case you have just as many draw-calls per frame. This can likely be optimized by merging all of the boxes into a single geometry which can be used by a single mesh (and a single draw-call.)

Comment: There's about 15000 meshes being added. I tried merging the meshes, but I ended up with just a single block on the screen, but I may just not fully understand merging. If I did merge the meshes, would I be able to easily remove a box from the screen with `scene.remove(object)`?

Comment: 15000 is a lot of individual meshes to have in a scene at any given time. "Merging" in this case means instead of adding a new mesh for each box, you translate the geometry to the desired position, and then copy it as vertices into the shared geometry object. You might need to look into using a combination of techniques such as frustum culling, quadtrees/octrees, etc. -- in order to optimize performance.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment, in combination with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422289/three-js-merging-geometries-and-mesh helped me get the merging thing working. It now usually gets 10-20% cpu usage, and is much smoother. Thanks!